# php dom document remove special characters

Tags: php, domdocument

im using dom document getElementsByTagName to retrieve a website title.

here is my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($strData);
$doc->encoding = 'utf-8';
$doc->saveHTML();
$titleNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
```

it works fine but when there is special character in the title, the retrieve data is not accurate. im getting "`Some More Google Plus Invite Workarounds #wrapper { background:url(/) no-repeat 50% 0; } body { background:#CFD8E2; }`" instead.

i did the following to replace the special chars but it didnt work:

```
// Replace all special characters into space
    $specialChars = array('~','`','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','=','+','|','\\',']','[','}','{','"','\'',':',';','/','?','.',',','>','<');
        foreach ($specialChars as $a) {
         $titleNode = str_replace($a, ' ', $titleNode);

    }
```

im getting empty title instead. The `<title>` value is somthing like this:

```
<title>Some More Google Plus Invite Workarounds  < Communication, Social Networking < PC World India News < PC World.in</title>
```

so what should i be doing

Comment: Hmm, is it reading the "less than" (<) as the beginning of a html tag?

Comment: yup it is.. and after reading that, it jump to read the css styles.

Comment: ok i just wanna add on that str_replace now works for me because earlier the $titleNode wasnt't a string. so i replace this instead $titleNode->item(0)->nodeValue.. however, the title retrieved is still not accurate. i should not be getting the css styles in the title

Comment: @Mark, if a title is all he needs, it may be a lot easier to just read the html and do a quick regex on the on the title tag.  Not sure if this is a bug or not that needs reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your HTML is not well formed. If you have a stray `<` in the title, I'm surprised that you're not getting `Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): error parsing attribute name in Entity, line: 1 in <path> on line <line>`.

As to replacing: if you replace all of the `<` and `>` in an html document, you'll not be able to retrieve elements from it: there will not be any elements left:

```
<head><title>Foo</title></head>
```

Becomes

```
headtitleFoo/title/head
```

Unfortunately, not much can be done to fix this -- bad HTML is bad HTML. If you know that you can expect that type of problem ahead of time, then you might be able to do something with preg_replace (maybe `preg_replace("#\s<\s#g",'&lt;',$input);`? `preg_match('#title[^>]*>(.*)</title#', $input, $matches)`?) or substr, but you might just be up a creek.

Comment: yeap the html page im crawling is not well formed. what i did is to replace the < > in the title value only. so it wont affect the rest of the html =D

Answer (score 0):

i had a look the site; and it's a problem because they don't use the proper html-entities in the title:

```
<title>Some More Google Plus Invite Workarounds  < Communication, Social Networking < PC World India News < PC World.in</title>
```

i assume that DOMDocument has an issue with that and thinks this is where the tag ends. As a workaround you could add '< ' to $specialChars to dodge this problem.

Comment: added!!. currently im just using str_replace so that it wont cause the page to crash. by not doing so, my website crash the moment it display the title

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.domain.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";    
    $out .= "Host: www.domain.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    $buffer = '';
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $buffer .= fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
            preg_match('#<.*?title.*?>(.*?)<.*?title.*?>#', $buffer, $matches); 
            var_dump($matches);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that regex match `<div class="title">Something</div><div class="other-title">Something else</div>`

Comment: i shall try ur solution and let u noe later =D

Comment: @cwallenpoole I suppose you are right.  Might need to revamp that a little nuttynibbles to avoid false positives like mentioned.